# Connecting parts with sides with different curvature in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I have two parts: a washer and a rectangular prism.

[image]

I need to connect them side by side. But the joined sides have different curvature.

[image]

How can I merge the sides so that the details look something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make the rectangular portion larger,

[image]

and then apply a fillet at the intersection points.